# Do I have to migrate my question to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, migration, stackoverflow

Hi I posted [AHK script is unstable while running](https://superuser.com/q/976442/396887), but I got a comment that I need to migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Do I really have to migrate it?

Answer (score 7):

People are a little overzealous about suggesting an alternate site for things.

Scripting languages for desktop applications are on topic here. Bash, AHK and PS would more often than not be on topic here, unless you were abusing them in unspeakable ways. Python, depends on what you do. C and such go to SO.

In this case the comment is incorrect, and well *gone*.

Comment: It would be useful to have guidance somewhere on what "programming" is appropriate to migrate to SO.  VBA has been clarified previously.  OS commands and batch files clearly belong here.  Shell commands and scripts stay here.  Low level languages that require compiling clearly go to SO.  High level scripting languages seem to be a gray area.  If all of this could be aggregated in a canonical answer, along with guidance and/or examples, it would be really helpful.  Right now, it's more "I know it when I see it", and in many cases, it's not very clear.

Comment: Does it basically come down to what you're doing rather than the language, specifically?  Action to solve a specific computer problem = here; development = SO?  Pretty much anything you would do with C++ would be development.  Scripting within an end-user application (like AHK), or any OS or shell is on-topic.  That leave scripting languages that are generally used for programming, like Python.  When would that be on-topic here?

Answer (score 5):

No, AutoHotKey is a scripting language and is thus pretty well on-topic for Super User.

However, what you're trying to do, and the way you're going about it, is not a very good solution for the task you're assigned to do, as I've commented on your main question. Just be aware of that.